# Read String Until Space Then Split - Java

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string in Java?
I would like to read a string until there is a space.
Then split it into a different string after the space.

e.g. String fullcmd = `/join luke`
I would like to split it into:
String cmd = `/join`
String name = `luke`
OR
String fullcmd = `/leave luke`
I would like to split it into:
String cmd = `/leave`
String name = `luke`

So that I can:

```
if(cmd.equals"/join") System.out.println(name + " joined.");
else if(cmd.equals"/leave" System.out.println(name + " left.");
```

I did think about doing `String cmd = fullcmd.substring(0,5);`
But cmd's length varies depending on the command.

Comment: string.split(' ')?  that will split the string on spaces, giving you an array as a result.  So if you have "/join luke" and split() that on spaces, you'd have array element 0 = "/join" and array element 1 = "luke".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's easiest if you use `String.split()`

```
String[] tokens = fullcmd.split(" ");
if(tokens.length!=2){throw new IllegalArgumentException();}
String command = tokens[0];
String person = tokens[1];
// now do your processing
```

Comment: Thanks I have used this in my program

Answer (score 4):

Use [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split).

In your case, you would use

```
fullcmd.split(" ");
```

Comment: I think he wants fullcmd.split(" ") ?

Answer (score 3):

As is was mentioned by darioo use [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Pay attention that the argument is not a simple delimiter but regular expression, so in your case you can say: `str.split('\\s+')` that splits your sentence into separate words event if the words are delimited by several spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing from command line argument, there is an [apache commons cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) which parse command line arguments into objects for you.